# matrix sampling and its rank preservation

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

1. Assuming matrix $X\in R^{m\times n}$ is row orthogonal of rank $m$. Then, if I construct a new matrix $Y\in R^{m\times t}$, whose columns are directly sampled from $X$ with or without replacement according to some probability distribution. My question is: what is the smallest $t$ to make $Y$ of rank $m$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need two results:

1. The rank of a matrix is inferior or equal to its dimensions. In your case $rank(Y)\le \min (m,t)$. So you will need $t\ge m$.
2. A matrix has rank $m$ if it has a non-zero minor of order $m$ and all minors of strictly superior order are zero. Therefore, your matrix $X$ has a non-zero minor of order $m$. If your sample $Y$ hits the necessary columns to recreate one of that non-zero minor, then $Y$ will have rank $m$. Therefore, $t=m$ is sufficient to (eventually) reproduce $Y$ of rank $m$.

[Minors on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29)

[Rank on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I do not know what is the corresponding probability distribution by which we can get your result $t=m$?